# What is the difference between a creditor and a lender?

Tags: accounting

Can you share specific examples?
Also, when are they the same entity and when are they different?

Comment: simple search would answer this, homework questions don't help anyone in general.

Comment: Homework questions are allowed on the site, as long as they are useful to others. This one, maybe not so much.

Comment: OP: it's the same thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lender lends money to a person or institution.

A creditor is owed money by the person or institution. Many times they are equal. But if you owe money to somebody they are a creditor. You could have paid with a check, but it bounced. Or you contracted them for a service, and then never paid for that service.

Yes technically a creditor did offer a short term that was supposed to be paid within X days of being billed.

Sometimes a creditor works the other way also. You gave a deposit to company X for them to remodel your kitchen. They never start the job. They now owe you a refund of your deposit. You are now a creditor.